# certbot-auto ImportError: No module named _ssl

Tags: linux, debian, debian-jessie, letsencrypt, certbot

Running certbot-auto gives this output:

> Error: couldn't get currently installed version for ...
>
> File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 140, in init_static_locks
> **import**("_ssl")
> ImportError: No module named _ssl

This occurred after a dist-upgrade from Debian 7 -> Debian 8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

certbot-auto uses its own installed virtual environment, including its own build of python. This was (naturally) not updated in the dist-upgrade to Jessie.  certbot-auto did not detect that it needed a rebuild, thinking that all the dependencies were satisfactorily *already* installed.

So the fix was:

```
rm -rf /opt/eff.org
/usr/local/bin/certbot-auto
```

which then downloaded and rebuilt all that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

I also upgraded a system from Debian 7 to Debian 8, but found no file with the name "certbot-auto". So I renamed /opt/eff.org to /opt/eff.org.old and started letsencrypt-auto which downloaded the necessary files.

Comment: `letsencrypt-auto` is the *really old* name for `certbot-auto`.